# How to add custom 3d object materials (.mtl) over custom 3d objects(.obj)?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to render a 3d object using react-three-fiber. I was able to import custom 3d object, but I am not able to apply custom material on the object. Any help would be really appreciated.
Below is the code I have tried so far

```
let mat = useLoader(MTLLoader,'/public/IronMan.mtl')
    const objec = useLoader(OBJLoader,url, object =>
      {

        object.setMaterials(mat)
        console.log(object)
      })
    const loader = new OBJLoader();
       loader.load(url,
        function(obj)
        {
          console.log("loaded")
         // console.log(obj)
        });
       // const objec = useLoader(OBJLoader,url)
    console.log(objec)

    loader.setMaterials(mat)
   // console.log(loader)
    //console.log(mat)
    //objec.setMaterials(mat)

    //let mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();

    //let objLoader = new OBJLoader();

    // mtlLoader.load('/public/IronMan.mtl', (materials) => {
    //   materials.preload()
    //   objLoader.setMaterials(materials)
    //   objLoader.load('./test.obj', (object) => {
    //     scene.add(object)
    //   })
    // })

    return (
    <mesh material-color='red'>
      <primitive object={objec}/>
      <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="yellow" transparent />
      </mesh>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`OBJLoader` always returns an object of type `THREE.Group` which is more or less a container object for renderable items like meshes, points or lines. Hence, you can't apply a material to it.

In the official [OBJ loader example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj), the materials are modified like so:

```js
object.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child.isMesh ) child.material.map = texture;

} );
```

Instead of assigning a diffuse texture, you can also change the entire material.

`three.js R109`

Comment: In react-three-fiber the group object could then be outright declared:

    <primitive object={object.children[0]}>
      <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color="yellow" transparent />

if it's a gltf it can be done automatically: https://github.com/react-spring/gltfjsx but it can be done by hand.